# fetch_fields() using DBAL doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, dbal

I want to get the field name using doctrine DBAL

this is my sql query:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $connection = $em->getConnection();
  $listcontact = $connection->prepare("select * from contact");
  $listcontact->execute();
```

how I can get the name of fields using DBAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the schema manager of Doctrine DBAL :

```
// Get schema manager : 
$sm = $connection->getSchemaManager();
// Get fields list from table 'contact' :
$columns = $sm->listTableColumns('contact');
// Loop over the array to get names and other properties : 
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo $column->getName() . ': ' . $column->getType() . "\n";
}
```

Complete doc of schema manager is here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html